# Collecting html form data + attachment and sending with php

Tags: php, html, ajax, json

I have a online shop. The payment needs to be done with bank transfer, now everything works fine but when I submit and send the email the attachment I receive is corrupt and I do not see any 'text' in the mail.

I would like the email that I receive to include all the form data and the attachment

Here is my code

```
    <?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_Email       = "sean@seankonig.co.za"; //Replace with recipient email address
    $subject        = 'Website Order'; //Subject line for emails



    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=>'error',
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));

        die($output);
    }

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userOrder"]) || !isset($_POST["userPhone"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Input fields are empty!'));
        die($output);
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Order       = filter_var($_POST["userOrder"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Phone       = filter_var($_POST["userPhone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<4) // If length is less than 4 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Order)) //check entered data is numbers
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter Order Number!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!is_numeric($user_Phone)) //check entered data is numbers
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Only numbers allowed in phone field'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($user_Message)<0) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }

    ### Attachment Preparation ###
    $file_attached = false; //initially file is not attached

    if(isset($_FILES['file_attach'])) //check uploaded file
    {
        //get file details we need
        $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['file_attach']['tmp_name'];
        $file_name        = $_FILES['file_attach']['name'];
        $file_size        = $_FILES['file_attach']['size'];
        $file_type        = $_FILES['file_attach']['type'];
        $file_error       = $_FILES['file_attach']['error'];

        //exit script and output error if we encounter any
        if($file_error>0)
        {
            $mymsg = array(
            1=>"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini",
            2=>"The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form",
            3=>"The uploaded file was only partially uploaded",
            4=>"No file was uploaded",
            6=>"Missing a temporary folder" );

            $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => $mymsg[$file_error]));
            die($output);
        }

        //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
        $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

        //now we know we have the file for attachment, set $file_attached to true
        $file_attached = true;
    }

    if($file_attached) //continue if we have the file
    {
        # Mail headers should work with most clients (including thunderbird)
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .= "From:".$user_Email."\r\n";

        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$user_Email."" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=".md5('boundary1')."\r\n\r\n";

        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;  boundary=".md5('boundary2')."\r\n\r\n";

        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary2')."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $message = '<html><body>';
        $message.='</div>';
        $message.= $user_Name;
        $message.= $user_Phone;
        $message.= $user_Order;
        $message.= $user_Email;

        $message .= $user_Message."\r\n\r\n";

        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary2')."--\r\n";
        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type:  ".$file_type."; ";
        $headers .= "name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Disposition:attachment; ";
        $headers .= "filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Attachment-Id:".rand(1000,9000)."\r\n\r\n";
        $headers .= $encoded_content."\r\n";
        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."--";
    }else{
        # Mail headers for plain text mail
        $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    }

    //send the mail
    $sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Message, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail) //output success or failure messages
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_Name .' Thank you for the payment. We will be in contact'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

I hope you someone can help sort this out.

Comment: How about using standalone Zend_Mail or sth similar and well tested to handle that bit for you?

Comment: I suppose but I want to know why this is not working.

Comment: @Jarek.D : Before use framework, learn how it s work , no ?
No answer but check : -     strange line   `$message = '<html><body>';
        $message.='</div>';` - in your form `enctype="multipart/form-data"` isset ?

Comment: Zend_Mail can be used as standalone module so you don't have to dig into the whole framework. And the reason I'd typically use in that sort of situations is: I don't have time to deal with all the quirky issues related to multipart headers and rely instead on well tested component

Comment: Okay I will check it out. If anyone does find the issue here though please let me know. I really want this to work. Thanks @Jarek.D